# How to customize a property inside a ContentControl in the "Pressed" VisualState?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm building Windows Phone app and I created a custom icon button that will be used over and over again. The button looks pretty much like the following picture:

[image: Button mockup]

To try to follow the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle I created a class that basically inherited from `Button` and added a custom parameter of type `ControlTemplate` called **`IconTemplate`**

*I omitted the part about the property for the `Text` for brevity*

```
public class IconButton : Button
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconTemplateProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register(
                    "IconTemplate",
                    typeof(ControlTemplate),
                    typeof(IconButton),
                    null);

    public ControlTemplate IconTemplate
    {
        get { return (ControlTemplate)GetValue(IconTemplateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconTemplateProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

After creating the class I made a `Resource` called `Generic.xaml` that applied some style to this class.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:c="clr-namespace:PiadasEngracadas.Controls"

    <Style TargetType="c:IconButton">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="c:IconButton">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" x:Name="ButtonBackground">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="IconTemplateContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                         </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                         <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
                                          </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="IconTemplateContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="IconTemplateContainer"
                                        Template="{TemplateBinding IconTemplate}" />
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                   Margin="{StaticResource PhoneHorizontalMargin}"
                                   FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyLight}"
                                   Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" />
                    </Grid>              
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

So I could simply create the button like this and the appearance would be correct.

```
<c:IconButton Text="Some Text"
              IconTemplate="{StaticResource IconsButtons.Sleepy}" />
```

**The problem is that I want to change the `Path's Stroke` color when the user taps the button.**

Since I'm going to use this button over and over again I thought that maybe it would be valuable to have another property that it would define the new stroke color when the button is tapped. Something like:

```
<c:IconButton Text="Some Text"
              TappedColor="#123456" // New property
              IconTemplate="{StaticResource IconsButtons.Sleepy}" />
```

But the problem is that I don't know how to change the color of the `Path` that is the `Template` (?) of the `ContentControl`. I was thinking about something like this:

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="(IconTemplateContainer).(Template).(Stroke)">
```

I know that this syntax is completely wrong but I wonder if someone can help me achieve my goal.

*PS: I'm wrapping all the `Path`s in a `ControlTemplate` because using the `Path` directly and just binding it to the `Content` property of the `ContentControl` doesn't work on WP (or at least I'm not smart enough to make it work). Even in this case, how would I change a property of a object inside the `ContentControl`s Content`for a certain`VisualState`?*

**UPDATE**

The `ControlTemplate` code is as follows

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="IconsButtons.Sleepy">
    <Path Data="M32.000099,44.658999C36.566562,44.658999 39.162999,47.058804 ...."
          Stretch="Uniform"
          Fill="#FFFFFFFF"
          Width="26"
          Height="26"
          Margin="0"
          RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Path.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <TransformGroup.Children>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                </TransformGroup.Children>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Path.RenderTransform>
    </Path>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: How about overriding the `MouseDown` event in your custom button and changing the `Path` stroke from there?

Comment: Sounds like you could do a TemplateBinding on the stroke color of the path to the foreground color of your IconButton. Then you can change the Foreground color of the IconButton and it will change the path color: `Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"`

Comment: If you can post the ContentTemplate code that contains the Path as well that would be helpful.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to access the stroke color of the `Path` since it's inside the `ContentControl` in my Resource file

Comment: A TemplateBinding is for that exact purpose: binding properties from inside the template to properties on the outer control that is using them. I may be misunderstanding you. Can you clarify more for me?

Comment: @bauric You're right, I had a misconception about how the TemplateBinding worked. I added the `Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foregroud}` to the `ControlTemplate.Path` as you suggested and now when I change the `ContentControl.Foreground` property it also changes the `ControlTemplate.Path.Stroke`. Now I'm still facing another problem: I added an `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames` referencing the `ContentControl.Foreground` to the `VisualState.Pressed` state. I tried to bind the new value to a property that I created `Value="{TemplateBinding TapStrokeBrush}"` but it doesn't work.

Comment: @baueric When I change the binding to another brush, say `{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}` it works fine, but when I bind to the property `SolidBrush IconButton.TapStrokeBrush` the stroke actually disappears whenever I tap the button. Perhaps its value is somehow `{x:Null}`? I'm setting its value like `<c:IconButton IconTemplate="{StaticResource IconsButtons.Laugh}" Text="Some Text" TapStrokeBrush="#0078B8" />`

Comment: Look at the console output for any errors. That may help you figure out if the binding was unsuccessful or there was a conversion error somewhere in the binding.

Comment: I believe there wasn't any binding issue as when I tried to use the `TapStrokeBrush` outside of the `VisualState.Pressed` it worked fine. The debug didn't show anything also. It looks like it doesn't work inside the `VisualState`, using `{Binding TapStrokeBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}` instead of `{TemplateBinding TapStrokeBrush}` made it work there. I really want to know how, since I read that they are both semantically identical.

Comment: @baueric Thanks a lot for your help. Couldn't make without it :). Would you mind answering the question just like your first comment so I can mark it as the answer and add some remarks?

Comment: No problem I added the answer. That is odd. Maybe TemplateBinding doesn't work inside of a VisualState unless you add that RelativeSource part. Glad you figured out your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a TemplateBinding on the stroke color of the path to the foreground color of your IconButton. Then you can change the Foreground color of the IconButton and it will change the path color: Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"

Comment: This indeed worked for me. What I basically did was to add the property `SolidBrush IconButton.TapStrokeBrush` to my class then inside the **`ControlTemplate`** I added `Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"` and for the `Generics.xaml's ContentControl` I made the binding `<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="IconTemplateContainer"><DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding TapStrokeBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" /></ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>` inside the `VisualState.Pressed`